# MPMusicPlayerController Does Not Control Podcast App in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, mpmusicplayercontroller, podcast

`MPMusicPlayerController` does not control the podcast app in iOS 7.  Is there a way to pause, start, and seek a playing podcast in iOS 7 (podcast was started playing with the Podcast app).

If I do `[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] play]` it stops the podcast and starts a music MP3.

`[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] play]` does not work either.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I am bumping up against the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the playlist to podcasts to play podcasts, like so:

```
MPMusicPlayerController  *player = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery podcastsQuery];
MPMediaItemCollection *collection =
    [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:[query items]];
```

`[player setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];`

`[player play];`

Comment: There's a working podcast example app at http://github.com/DavidPhillipOster/podbiceps

Comment: Perfectly true but doesn't answer the question, which is about detecting what happened in the Podcasts app.